# BadMethodCallException Method App\Http\Controllers\CvController::create does not exist

Tags: laravel

Having the issue when loading the cvs/create being return an error of;

[image: Error]

My route file;

[image: Route File]

My CvController;

[image: CvController]

Application frames (1)

[image: Application frames]

Comment: in your exception trace press the `Application Frames (1)` and select the eception and show us the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your route

```
CvController@create
```

but in your CvController

```
public function cerate()
```

spellings mistake.

```
create != cerate
```

Comment: rude... but effective.

Answer (score 0):

There is a spell mistake in your function

```
public function create() {
   return view('cv.create');
}
```